# Subsurface value of principled BSDF shader affects other materials with subsurface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

[image]

As the picture shows when I decrease the value of subsurface for one material (skin in this case), other materials (around the eye) that also use subsurface are getting black even though they are all separate materials. Does principled bsdf somehow just share this value across all its instances or what exactly is going on, is this a bug?

Comment: Are you certain you're creating new materials and not applying the same instance to different meshes?

Comment: Yes, I changed the gif so now it is more obvious with subsurface on eyes. Skin and Eye are using completely different materials with their own node setup. Both are using principled bsdf tho.

Comment: Could you quickly check if this still happens when you use Cycles? Afaik, the SSS in Eevee is not raytraced, but rather "fake". So it might be a settings issue.

Comment: Yes, happens with cycles as well.

Comment: I am not at a computer right now, but at first I would suspect, if the eye and the skin use subsurface scattering, light travels through these objects. If you are then decreasing the subsurface scattering on the skin, the eye gets less light from the "inside", from the head behind and to the side and maybe this darkens the eye. Just a wild guess though.